# Why isn't my CSS working when I try to target a div tag with the class "row" and an id?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm new to bootstrap 4 and am using the class "row" in multiple places. I want to add a margin-left to just one of these div tags with the class row, so I added an id to the div tag.

```
<div id="menumargin" class="row">
```

when I use this CSS

```
.row{
margin-left: -15px !important;
}
```

it works but affects all instances of row obviously.
However this CSS I write to just target this instance:

```
#menumargin.row{
margin-left: -15px !important;
}
```

doesn't work. It's as if the code isn't written at all.

Please advise.

I hope this question makes sense. I'm also new to Stack Overflow.

Comment: bootstrap `.row` class gives `margin: 0 !important;` to the DOM and if you want to overwrite that margin, you need to specify `!important` tag in your CSS

Answer (score 0):

Columns have horizontal padding to create the gutters between individual columns, however, you can remove the margin from rows and padding from columns with .no-gutters on the .row.
The gutters between columns in our predefined grid classes can be removed with .no-gutters. This removes the negative margins from .row and the horizontal padding from all immediate children columns.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row no-gutters">
    <div class="col">col</div>
    <div class="col">col</div>
    <div class="col">col</div>
    <div class="col">col</div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8">col-8</div>
    <div class="col-4">col-4</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have an article about bootstrap here [How to Responsive Design with Bootstrap?](https://medium.com/@patty03/how-to-responsive-design-with-bootstrap-ac9ffa6b02b9)